# how to detect NaN from console input?

Tags: assembly, lc3

Am suppose to exit a loop when ctrl+d(x04) is typed in lc-3
so I'm trying to detect this from console input by using getc.

Is there a easy way doing this?
Or I have to convert input to a negative number and add with x04?

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to check R0 to see if it is set to 4.

A marginally easier way would be to simply add -4 to the input rather than inverting the input and adding +4.